# If I try to make an armature for my model and I extrude the bones and then deselect the extruded bone, I can’t select it again,what should I do?

Tags: armature, extrude

I have been making a character and I want to give it an armature (I did do it once) but if I extrude the first bone, and then deselect the second bone, I can’t select the second bone again. The only bone I can select after deselecting is the first bone. Does anyone know what to do?